# Accessing javascripts in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to serve an application in which an html file calls javascript that is located in a separate file. I placed the javascript file in the javascripts fold of my rails application. My html displays fine but when I press a button that is intended to call a javascript function I receive an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'myMethod' of undefined
```

I can see that the file is present by looking in the resources tab of google chromes developer tools. It also looks like rails is correctly including the javascript file in the html file.

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/myScript.js?body=1"></script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like it's the error of JavaScript itself nothing to do with rails... can you paste the code of it?

Comment: Show us the code, man! We want to help you!

Comment: True. "of undefined" suggests that "myMethod" is a function on an object that isn't defined. Post myScript.js and the line of HTML that's attempting to call the function "myMethod".

Comment: https://github.com/jacthoma/sequencewithme. The html file is the same index.html from that github link, minus the javascript and css includes. The javascript is sequence.js in the javascript folder. I'm trying to reimplement the same web app using ruby on rail, for a class. Everything works fine with node.js so I'm quite a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use the [javascript_include_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) helper to keep the app to convention:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "myScript" %>
```

The error is to do with your Javascript's call to `myMethod`. The error will be caused by referencing `myMethod` on an object / var which doesn't exist